# How does removing one link delete a node from a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I was reading through the code in the Crashing the Coding Interview book and when they delete a node in page 93, this is a snippet of the code they use:

```
Node deleteNode(Node head, int d){ 

while (n.next != null) {

if (n.next.data == d){
  n.next == n.next.next;
  return head;
  }

return head;
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is why this deletes the previous n.next node if the previous n.next node would still have a link to the node after it? I attached an illustration the help explain.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: `b` is not references by anyone anymore and Java has automatic garbage collection of objects that are not references anymore. So `b` will be trashed since nobody links it. Hence link-removal is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In languages/runtime supporting automatic garbage collection, the object referenced by this reference variable (`b` - unable to reach from any live thread of execution) will be garbage collected.
2. Even in such cases, care should be taken to close any external resources properly (example - someone assigns a value stored in object referenced by `b` to their static reference).
3. In runtimes without automatic garbage collection, it is the developer's responsibility to deallocate the resources.

Answer (score 3):

When we code with Java the Node that contain the b value will be removed by the garbage collector (GC) in the Java virtual machine (JVM). But with C language you should destroy this Node using free() function.
this is an example of creation and destruction of one node in C (we assume that "struct node" already defined) :

```
n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
free(n);
```